# NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute doesn't work with NSFontAttributeName

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

### Story

App receives strings with html tags that were edited in CMS. App receives that strings and put to `UILabel`. Not so long ago html tags were added to this strings. Obviously strings with html tags looks fine in site.

I made an investigation and found that we can use attributed strings for `UILabel`.

```
//attributes dictionary
NSDictionary *attrs =
@{
     NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
 };

NSAttributedString* attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[textString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] 
                                                                  options:attrs
                                                       documentAttributes:nil 
                                                                    error:nil];
```

Ok, now tags are enabled. But I lost my font, text looks like... default html text! That strings take their font's from css, but I receive bare strings with html tags. Just add `NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.f]` to `attrs` dictionary. But without any success.

I made second try with `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
//attributes dictionary
NSDictionary *attrs =
@{
     NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
 };

NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[textString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] 
                                                                  options:attrs
                                                       documentAttributes:nil 
                                                                    error:nil];
//and set font later
[attrString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length)];
```

And now I've got label without any html tags, but this last step overrides all changes(bold, italic, etc.) from tags.

### Question

**How can we use html tags in attributed strings but set our font for them?**

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for solution of this issue.
So far I Solved this by using the following code. Here I know HTML always contains Times new roman font. But If anybody find any dynamic solution please provide happily.

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [parsedAttributedString length]);
    [parsedAttributedString enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:range options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop)
    {
        UIFont* currentFont = value;
        UIFont *replacementFont = nil;

            if ([currentFont.fontName rangeOfString:@"BoldMT" options:NSLiteralSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                replacementFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0f];
            }
            else if ([currentFont.fontName rangeOfString:@"BoldItalicMT" options:NSLiteralSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                replacementFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic" size:14.0f];
            }
            else if ([currentFont.fontName rangeOfString:@"ItalicMT" options:NSLiteralSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                replacementFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" size:14.0f];
            }
            else
            {
                replacementFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:14.0f];
            }

            [parsedAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:replacementFont range:range];
    }];
```